# How do I remove a Quasar q-input prop on button click?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a [quasar](https://quasar.dev/) q-input element that I want to enable and disable at the click of a button.

I have added a button to the input using `v-slot:after` but I don't know how to remove the `disable` prop when it is clicked.

P.S. I am using Quasar + Vue 3 + TypeScript.

```
<template>
  <q-input
    disable
    type="text"
    autocomplete="given-name"
    label="First Name"
    v-model="firstName"
  >
    <template v-slot:after>
      <q-btn
        label="Edit"
        @click="handleClick"
      />
    </template>
  </q-input>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue';

const firstName: Ref<string | null> = ref(null);

const handleClick = () => {
  //Remove the "disable" prop from the q-input element
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In VUE you must think backwards.

1. Put in input :disable="myDisable"
2. Create the ref myDisable in the setup and put your initial value that you need true or false
3. In your handleClick change the value of myDisable =!myDisable